# Biber fails to find entry

Tags: biber

I am putting together a MWE for a question about `biblatex`, and while doing so, I'm at a loss to understand why this simple MWE fails. When running `biber`, I get the message `WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'smith1983' (section 0)`. I am running `biber` v.2.17 in texlive 2022.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1983,
    AUTHOR = "Harry Smith",
    TITLE = "My second book",
    YEAR = "1983"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{smith1983}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works OK for me. Check the .bib file has that entry, and clear all the temp files and do a clean run.

Comment: Crystal ball: You had a first version of the file with a different bibkey, compiled it, changed the key, but `filecontents` nowadays no longer overwrites by default (your example does give a warning of obsolete package), so you are left with the old `\jobname.bib`. If the crystal ball is correct, try `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}` (and let go of the `filecontents` package as it doesn't serve you much anyway).

Comment: @gusbrs Yes, I've reached a similar conclusion. `filecontents` is disabled during compiling, so it rather generates a `.bib` file with the same filename as my `.tex` file. The problem is that if I append anything to the `\jobname.bib` in my preamble, this is not appended to the `.bib` file. So I need to delete the generated `.bib` file every time I change anything in `\jobname.bib`. Btw, what _should_ we now use instead of `filecontents` when creating MWEs for bibliography questions?

Comment: @Sverre It's in the kernel, you can use the environment, just don't need the package. But the syntax is slightly different, just use the `[overwrite]` argument, as I've said, so you don't need to manually delete anything.

Comment: @gusbrs What I don't understand is that it still won't overwrite the old `jobname.bib` file, it just overwrites the `filename.bib` file (which is generated with the same filename as the `.tex` file). So what is then the purpose of having the `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}` and `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` lines?

Comment: @Sverre Sorry, I don't understand what you mean there, and can't reproduce. Using the optional argument to `filecontents` works as described for me here.

Comment: @gusbrs `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}` doesn't write a file `jobname.bib`.

Comment: @Sverre Well, of course not! `\jobname` is a macro which stores the name of the file being processed... If you really want a file `jobname.bib`, you should write `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{jobname.bib}`, but you can use any name there.

Comment: @gusbrs Ok. I had an old file `jobname.bib` in my directory, so I assumed the package `filecontents` had created it from `{\jobname.bib}`. But maybe I just once forgot to add the slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old `filecontents` environment existing in the kernel has been improved some time ago, such that the `filecontents` package currently passes control to the kernel. However, the kernel's `filecontents` environment is a little different from the one previously offered by the package in that it does not overwrite the file by default. If you want to overwrite the file, you must pass the optional argument `overwrite` or `force`. And you need no longer load the `filecontents` package (probably "should not", anyway not doing so gets rid of the warning).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{smith1983,
    AUTHOR = "Harry Smith",
    TITLE = "My second book",
    YEAR = "1983"}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{smith1983}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```